Can Sanctions Against Russia Be Modeled as a Dummy Variable in Econometric Analysis?
I am currently working on an econometric analysis where I aim to assess the impact of sanctions against Russia on the share of energy from renewable sources (% of total energy) in 28 EU countries.
I am considering modeling the sanctions as a dummy variable, where:
0 represents the periods when sanctions were not applied to Russia (before 2014).
1 represents the periods when sanctions were applied (2014 onwards).
My dependent variable is the share of energy from renewable sources in each of these countries over a specified time period.
I have a vector of control variables (GDP, energy prices, and policy incentives).
My questions are:
Is it appropriate to use a dummy variable to represent the imposition of sanctions in this context?
Are there any specific econometric models or techniques that would be recommended for analyzing the impact of such a binary treatment variable on a continuous outcome variable like the share of renewable energy?
I appreciate any insights or recommendations on best practices for this type of analysis!
